# iterating over the values of a list of ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, performance, iterator, hash-map

I am facing the following problem: I have a special data structure that is a dictionary whose keys are integers (dimensions). The values are also dictionaries whose keys are strings (geometric types) and whose values are numpy arrays (connectivities). Something like this:

```
custom = {1: {'a': np.zeros(10), 'b': np.zeros(100)}, 2:{'c': np.zeros(20), 'd': np.zeros(200)}}
```

I use this data structure quite a lot in the code, and every time I need to iterate over all rows in the numpy arrays of this data structure (all values of the dictionaries), I have to type:

```
for d, delem in custom.items():
    for k, v in delem.items():
        for row in v:
            print(row)
```

And this is way too verbose. So to make things easier to other developers, I am trying to encapsulate this behavior in a custom class so that I can type:

```
for row in custom:
    print(row)
```

Also, an important requirement is that all rows have to be traversed "in order".
And so I came up with a `Test` class that derives from `list`. The class is initialized by passing a dictionary (maybe I can improve this later by just adding the elements directly to it). I have overridden the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods to provide the iteration type I want. By default, iteration is done through the highest dimension present. But the user can do iteration over lower-dimensional dictionaries and for that I overrode the `__call__` method.
The technique works, I an iterate as many times as I want over this data structure, and I accomplished the simplicity I wanted. But I'm a bit concerned about performance, as I don't think that calling `self[self.d][self.etype][self.idx-1]` is very efficient. Maybe there are other improvements to be made as well that I don't see.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

custom = {0: {'n1': np.array([[3]])}, 1: {'l2': np.array([[ 0,  4],
       [ 4,  5],
       [40, 41],
       [41, 42],       [57,  3],
       [57,  3]])}, 2: {'t3x': np.array([[188, 401, 400],
       [188, 187, 401],
       [187, 205, 401],
       [324, 306, 417],
       [306, 305, 417],
       [305, 416, 417]]), 'q3': np.array([[188, 401, 400, 0],
       [188, 187, 401, 0],
       [187, 205, 401, 0],
       [323, 324, 417, 0],
       [324, 306, 417, 0],
       [306, 305, 417, 0],
       [305, 416, 417, 0]])}}


class Test(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Test, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for k,v in args[0].items():
            self[k] = OrderedDict(v)

        self.d = -1
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.iterator = iter(self[self.d].keys())
        self.etype = next(self.iterator)
        self.idx = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        self.setup()
        return self

    def __next__(self):

        try:
            self.idx += 1
            return self[self.d][self.etype][self.idx-1]

        except IndexError:

            self.etype = next(self.iterator)
            self.idx = 0
            return self[self.d][self.etype][self.idx-1]

    def __call__(self, d):
        self.d = d-1
        return self


def main(argv=()):

    tst = Test(custom)
    print(tst)

    # iterate over the container
    for el in tst:
        print(el)

    # iterate again over the container
    for el in tst:
        print(el)

    # iterate over lower dimension
    for el in tst(-1):
        print(el)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Don't change your code in response to answers.

Comment: I did it because your code is not addressing my issue exactly. Could you then edit your answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**yield!**

You're way overthinking the problem. Python has `yield`. This is one of the coolest things in Python (IMHO). When you want to iterate over a container like this:

```
for d, delem in custom.items():
    for k, v in delem.items():
        for row in v:
            print(row)
```

You just write a function that looks pretty much exactly like that:

```
def iter_over_custom(custom):     ## or a better name
    for _, delem in custom.items():
       for _, v in delem.items():
           for row in v:
               yield row
```

We can even drop the last loop if you have a sufficiently recent version of Python that supports `yield from`:

```
def iter_over_custom(custom):     ## or a better name
    for _, delem in custom.items():
       for _, v in delem.items():
           yield from v
```

Or you don't actually need `.items()` since you just need the values:

```
def iter_over_custom(custom):
    for delem in custom.values():
        for v in delem.values():
            yield from v
```

That's it. No need for a custom class to effectively reimplement the same. The initial loop could them be written as:

```
for row in iter_over_custom(custom):
    print(row)
```

---

Note that if you had your own class, you could write the above in `__iter__` too:

```
class Custom(object):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        for delem in self.whatever.values():
            for v in delem.values():
                yield from v
    ...
```

Comment: But using this approach I still don't have the `for c in custom:` syntax, do I? Nor I can't iterate over lower-dimensional dictionaries?

Comment: @aaragon You have `for c in iter_over_custom(custom)`. Or you can make `custom` its own class and define `__iter__` as what I wrote `iter_over_custom` to be (`__iter__` can `yield`).

Comment: I think I like this last suggestion but I'm not sure I understand exactly how to do that. I create a class, say `Custom`, and I override the `__iter__` method and put inside what you wrote. That's it?

Comment: @aaragon Yep. `__iter__` can return a generator.

Comment: Ok I see. Now, I'm new to Python so this code seems quite complex. I don't understand the `_` in the `for` loops. Also, this generator that is returned is iterating over the `whatever` dictionary, but in my data structure I have a list of `whatever` dictionaries. So if I want to go to a lower dimension, then that means I have to change the `whatever` dictionary. Should I store a variable to determine this and override `__call__` to change this variable as I've done it above?

Comment: @aaragon `_` is for things you don't care about - just name them `_` to indicate that they won't be used again. No idea why you would need `__call__`. Just look up what `yield` means and how it can be used.

Comment: You could also use `.values()` instead of `.items()` to avoid the need for `_` -- really just up to you.

Comment: It should be noted that the `yield from <expression>` form wasn't added until Python 3.3 according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions).