# Copying a Dictionary and Replace its Values

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a custom dictionary where the values are numpy arrays. I would like to have a convenience function that creates a copy of its content except that the values are changed. If no value is passed, then the default `None` is assigned to the keys, else a value is set. The function can also work with a callable function, and then the resulting value is obtained by passing the length of the numpy arrays.

Inspired by what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369247/copy-keys-to-a-new-dictionary-python), this is what I have so far:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

class CustomDict(dict):

    def strip(self, value=None):

        if callable(value):
            tmp = dict.fromkeys(self.keys())
            for k,v in self.items():
                tmp[k] = value(len(v))
            return tmp

        return dict.fromkeys(self.keys(), value)


def main(argv=()):

    tmp1 = CustomDict()

    tmp1['n1'] = np.array([[3]])
    tmp1['l2'] = np.array([[ 0,  4],
                            [ 4,  5],
                            [57,  3]])
    tmp1['t3x'] = np.array([[188, 401, 400],
                           [188, 187, 401],
                           [187, 205, 401],
                           [324, 306, 417],
                           [306, 305, 417],
                           [305, 416, 417]])

    # replace values
    print(tmp1.strip(1))

    # replace values with a callable function that gets the size of the array
    print(tmp1.strip(lambda x: [None]*x))

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

This code outputs:

```
{'l2': 1, 'n1': 1, 't3x': 1}
{'l2': [None, None, None], 'n1': [None], 't3x': [None, None, None, None, None, None]}
```

It's all good, it works. But I'm not sure the part that tackles the callable function is the most efficient one, as I am creating the copy of the dictionary first, and then I'm replacing the values with another loop. Can this be done in a single pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's often [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), nonetheless it's still sometimes preferable to [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl).

In this case, by making sure `value` is always something callable, the rest becomes simple if you use a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to create the value returned.

```
class CustomDict(dict):

    def strip(self, value=None):
        if not callable(value):
            saved_value, value = value, lambda _: saved_value
        return {k: value(v) for k,v in self.items()}

tmp1 = CustomDict()

tmp1['n1'] = np.array([[3]])
tmp1['l2'] = np.array([[ 0,  4],
                       [ 4,  5],
                       [57,  3]])
tmp1['t3x'] = np.array([[188, 401, 400],
                        [188, 187, 401],
                        [187, 205, 401],
                        [324, 306, 417],
                        [306, 305, 417],
                        [305, 416, 417]])

print(tmp1.strip(1))
print(tmp1.strip(lambda x: [None]*len(x)))
```

Comment: For this situation you're right indeed! It turns out that the `try, except` block was giving me all sorts of issues when passing a function and it's harder to debug.

Answer (score 5):

**Why an inherited class?**

I don't see anything about this problem that requires an inherited class. `strip` could just as easily be a free function:

```
def strip(dct, value=None):
    ...
```

Also `strip` isn't a particularly good name - it doesn't really resemble the `str.strip()` function. I don't know what a better one would be though:

**Callable**

If you're going to allow passing an arbitrary function, then I think you may as well pass the full value instead of just the length. If the caller wants the length, the caller can use `len` at that end. This'll enhance all the things you can do.

Also, in Python, [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp): it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. Just try to use the callable as a callable and catch the `TypeError`:

```
def strip(dct, value=None):
    try:
        tmp = dict.fromkeys(dct.keys())
        for k,v in dct.items():
            tmp[k] = value(v)
        return tmp
    except TypeError:
        return dict.fromkeys(dct.keys(), value)
```

**Dictionary comprehension**

For the `except` case - `fromkeys()` makes sense. But in the callable case, not really. You're creating a new dictionary and then re-modifying it. Better to just create the correct dictionary up front:

```
def strip(dct, value=None):
    try:
        return {k: value(v)
            for k,v in dct.items()
            }
    except TypeError:
        return dict.fromkeys(dct.keys(), value)
```

Comment: Thanks Barry for answering. The code I wrote was actually a stripped down version of the much more complex class (the list of ordered dictionaries discussed [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114568/iterating-over-the-values-of-a-list-of-ordered-dictionaries](here).
I agree that the name of the function is not the best, but I couldn't come up with anything better. Regarding passing the full value, this I can't do or I don't know how to do it properly, as the data structure is actually way more complex than the simple dictionary I put here.

Comment: @aaragon What do you mean you don't know how to pass the full value? You just... pass it. Also, if you want a complete review, post the complete code.